# Why does livedata return stale data from Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I have come across a problem that I am not being able to solve without implementing fragile hacks.

I have a table Users.

And I am observing it via LiveData.

Everytime I launch an update on that table , my observer invokes twice. Once with the old value , and then with the newly updated one.

To illustrate the problem I have created a small example I would share below

**UserDao.kt**

```
   @Dao
    interface UserDao {

        //region Inserts
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insertUser(user: User)
        @Update
        fun update(user:User)
@Query("select * from users ")
    fun users(): LiveData<List<User>>

}
```

I observe the live data in my MainActivity.

```
  observe(
            database.usersDao().users()
        ){
            Log.d("Here",it.name) // i first get the previous val then the new one
        }
```

And this is how i am registering an update also in the MainActivity

```
GlobalScope.launch {


            database.usersDao().update(
                User(
                    102,
                    "John",
                    "asdas",
                    roleCsv = "aaa",
                    accessToken = AccessToken("asd", "asd", 0),
                    loggedIn = false
                )
            )

        }
```

What transpires here is catastrophic for my system .

I get a user object that has a previous name , and then I get the updated "John"

the *observe* is just an extension method to easily register observers

```
fun <T : Any, L : LiveData<T>> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: L, body: (T) -> Unit) =
        liveData.observe(this, Observer(body))
```

My question was is this by design ?. Can I do something such that only the final picture from the database invokes my observer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend observing the following liveData in your case:

```
Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(database.usersDao().users())
```

**Source:**
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E)

On the other note, hold the liveData reference inside androidx's viewModel.